# Can't camelize in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I set the :id to Fight Force and run

```
    @monster_card_name = "#{params[:id]}Monster".constantize.camelize.all
```

I get Fighting ForceMonster, but I want FightingForceMonster. How would i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete *spaces* first.

```
"#{params[:id]}Monster".tr(" ","").camelize.constantize.all
```